# code organization in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class that spans over two files. It is declared in a **declare.h** file and defined in **define.cpp** file.

**define.h**

```
class A{
    public: int a;
            void func(){ a = some_other_func(); }
             A();
};
```

**define.cpp**

```
A::A(){
    a =0;
}
```

The overall idea is to initialize a variable in constructor before using it in an inline function. But the constructor definition and function definition are in different files. Is there any issue with this?

Comment: This is usually not a good practice, unless `declare.h` is including `define.h`; in that case the `define.h` is called the private or implementation part; usually people name it like `declare_priv.h` ...

Comment: is it `define.h` or `define.cpp`? Your question mentions both!

Comment: Beware that `int a = 0;` inside `A::A()` is not initializing `int A::a;`! In fact you are declaring a local variable. It should be simply `a = 0;` or even better to have `A::A() : a(0) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no issue with the declaration/definition separation, provided `declare.h` is included in `define.cpp`. But the usulal practice is for implementation files to have the same name as declaration files, bar the suffix. So your case could be `A.h` and `A.cpp`.

However, there is an issue with the initialization of member variable `a` itself. You may want to *initialize* `int a` in the constructor initialization list:

```
A::A() : a(0) {}
```

In your code, it is **not being initialized at all** . You are creating and initializing a local variable called `a` a local variable in the body of the constructor. Presumably that is not what you intended.

Comment: The issue is that `a` in constructor is a local variable and not a member variable, even if it was what happens is *Assignment* and not *Initialization*

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include "declare.h"` in `define.cpp` and then write constructor as `A::A() : a(0){}`.

Answer (score 0):

Though in general this is no technical issue with this. You should adopt the convention that the .h files are interfaces to your code and as such they should only have what is needed for some other code to call yours.

Comment: The issue is that `a` in constructor is a local variable and not a member variable, even if it was what happens is *Assignment* and not *Initialization*